# How to return a file and some data at once in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am sending an excel file with some data to insert in database.

For each line I have to validate the data, if the row has invalid data I must return the file with only invalid rows.

The download, reading and returning are working fine, but when I return the file containing the invalid values, I must update the modal by writing a text that tells the user that the downloaded file contains the rows with invalid data, so the user can rewrite and send back.

I am sending file by submiting and form, and receaving in the Action this way:

```
public ActionResult LoadData(HttpPostedFileBase _file)
```

and returning this way:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= Colabs.xlsx");

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    xlWorkbookFile.SaveAs(stream);
    stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: return not only the file, but also some data that can be read on client side.

Comment: Essentially you can't. That's not how HTTP works. You get one bite at the response apple. That's either an HTML document **or** a file download, never both. However, you *can* return an HTML document with a link to a file download, which is the typical way to go about it.

Comment: I solved by creating a cookie in response, then I created an event associated to submit in client, this event searches for this cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I founded was:

- Before submit, create an Interval that searches for a cookie that will be created in controller;
- You will store the extra data in cookies, and read them in javascript;

Creating cookie in controller:

```
Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("someDataCookieName", dataValue));
```

In JS, check for the values:

```
function CheckForValues() {
    intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
        var cookieValue = $.cookie('someDataCookieName');
        if (cookieValue == token) {
            alert(cookieValue)
        } else if (stopInterval) {
            clearInterval(intervalId );
            stopInterval = false;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

You can create your own condition for stop if any error occours.

Answer (score 1):

When you send content-disposition header with value as an attachment, that means browser treat that as downloaded file. The UI is never updated with that response

You can refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

To solve your issue, you should return your action result with Model(do not respond with the file), and in your view keep one hidden iframe pointing to that downloadable file(or URL of separate action which sends the file).